# Laravel 5.4: Listar informações de 4 tabelas relacionadas com a cláusula WITH

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Como podem ver no *controller Convenio*, estou listando as informações de cada convênio, juntamente com as informações que estão em outras tabelas(telefones, *endereco*), mas também gostaria de listar a especialidade e o tipo de serviço de cada um.

Diferente da tabela *telefones* e *endereço* que possui uma ligação direta com a tabela *convênio*, a especialidade e *serviço* não possuem (mas possuem a tabela *conv_serv* para fazer essa ligação).

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia trazer as informações dessas duas tabelas, através da cláusula *with*.

No final do post tem uma imagem explicando melhor a relação das tabelas.

MODEL CONVENIO

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Convenio extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'convenios';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'descricao', 'id_cidade'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function telefones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class, 'id_convenio', 'id');
    }

    public function endereco()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Endereco::class, 'id_convenio', 'id');
    }

    public function convServ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ConvServ::class, 'id_convenio','id');
    }

    public function cidade()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cidade::class, 'id_cidade', 'id');
    }
}
```

MODEL CONVSERV

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ConvServ extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'conv_servs';
    protected $fillable = ['id_convenio', 'id_especialidade'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function convenio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Convenio::class, 'id_convenio', 'id');
    }

    public function especialidade()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Especialidade::class, 'id_especialidade', 'id');
    }
}
```

MODEL ESPECIALIDADE

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Especialidade extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'especialidades';
    protected $fillable = ['nomeEsp', 'id_servico'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function convServ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ConvServ::class, 'id_especialidade','id');
    }
}
```

MODEL SERVICO

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servico extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'servicos';
    protected $fillable = ['nomeServ'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function especialidade()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Especialidade::class, 'id_servico', 'id');
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER CONVENIO

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Convenio;
use App\Models\Cidade;
use App\Models\Servico;
use App\Models\Especialidade;
use App\Models\Endereco;
use App\Models\ConvServ;
use App\Models\Telefone;
use DB;

class ConvenioController extends Controller
{
    private $convenio;

    public function __construct(Convenio $convenio)
    {
        $this->convenio = $convenio;
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->segment(1) == 'busca')
        {
            $title = 'Busca';
            $view = 'site.busca';
        }

        else
        {
            $title = 'Convênios';
            $view = 'painel.convenio.index';
        }

        $cidades = Cidade::pluck('nomeCidade', 'id')->all();

        $servicos = Servico::pluck('nomeServ', 'id')->all();

        $convenios = Convenio::with('telefones', 'endereco', 'cidade')
                            ->cidade($request->get('cidade'))
                            ->servico($request->get('servico'))
                            ->buscar($request->get('buscar'))
                            ->especialidade($request->get('especialidade'))
                            ->orderby('nome', 'asc')
                            ->paginate(10);

        return view($view, compact('title', 'convenios', 'cidades', 'servicos'));
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Diego tem relação errada, não tem? Convenios e Especialidades é no seu projeto qual relação?

Comment: Um convênio possui uma especialidade. Então criei uma tabela (conv_servs ) para armazenar as chaves estrangeiras dos dois.

Comment: A relação é muitos para muitos correto? se for no Eloquent está errada as configurações!

Comment: Por enquanto to usando só 1 pra 1, mas no futuro to pensando em deixar muitos para muitos, criei essa nova tabela já pensando nisso.

Comment: então está errado seu modelo de negócio, pelas tabelas apresentadadas, espero que entenda!

Comment: Mas isso não vai interferir na hora de trazer as informações né?

Comment: Vai limitar a sua regra, mas, vai trazer 1 registro seu eu não me engano, se tiver outros convenios inseridos vai causa problemas nesse aspectos!

Comment: Ok, então é só eu trocar lá no model do convênio, o hasOne por hasMany correto? Fazendo isso como ficaria pra trazer o nome do serviço e da especialidade na hora de listar os convênios?

Comment: Se for para alterar seria `belongsToMany`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exemplificar, vou criar um exemplo minimo só com a relação que precisa navegar entre as entidades, observe:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Convenios extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'convenios';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function especialidades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Especialidades::class,
            'convenios_especialidades',
            'convenio_id',
            'especialidade_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Especialidades extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'especialidades';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'servico_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function servico()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servicos::class, 'servico_id', 'id');
    }

    public function convenios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Convenios::class,
            'convenios_especialidades',
            'especialidade_id',
            'convenio_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servicos extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'servicos';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Essas relações seriam mediante aos relacionamentos de suas tabelas na imagem oferecida na sua pergunta, se quiser trazer os relacionamentos que são feitas a partir de `Convenios` faça:

```
App\Models\Convenios::with('especialidades.servico')->get();
```

Resultado:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#725
     all: [
       App\Models\Convenios {#743
         id: 1,
         name: "Con 1",
         especialidades: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#757
           all: [
             App\Models\Especialidades {#745
               id: 1,
               name: "Esp 1",
               servico_id: 1,
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#753
                 convenio_id: 1,
                 especialidade_id: 1,
               },
               servico: App\Models\Servicos {#759
                 id: 1,
                 name: "Serv 1",
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Explicação: para trazer as relação que é no próximo ***modelo de entidade*** separe por ponto passando o nome do método que faz a ligação no caso `especialidades.servico`, que é explicado na documentação: [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Vale lembrar que o seu modelo está diferente desse, mas, fiz de acordo com a relação das tabelas oferecidas no diagrama.

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Seguindo teu exemplo, para mostrar o nome das especialidades na view, não deveria ser preciso fazer só isso? @foreach($convenios as $convenio) {{$convenio->especialidades->name}} @endforeach

Comment: Não @DiegoVieira lembra que um relação `HasMany` ou `belongsToMany` gera uma coleção de resultados?

Comment: Ah verdade, consegui fazer mostrar os nomes. Mas o nome dos serviços não está mostrando, e não é uma relação muitos para muitos.

Comment: A relação de serviço é 1 para muitos @DiegoVieira, se viu no meu exemplo?

Comment: No teu exemplo não tem nenhuma relação lá no Model Servico, é por isso que não mostra os nomes, correto?

Comment: @DiegoVieira olha bem o resultado tem a chave de serviço lá mostrando! `servico: App\Models\Servicos {#759
                 id: 1,
                 name: "Serv 1",
               },` olha bem

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer utilizar o relacionamento das tabelas finais até chegar na tabela "Pai"... Sendo assim, pra lista de convênios tem tem a referência de conv_servs e assim por diante... Então a solução pra sair filtrando nas entidades mais abaixo pra por ultimo chegar na "convenios" é através de: [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Assim como no exemplo da documentação:

`$posts = Post::with(['votes', 'comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}])->get();`

E vai seguindo assim até chegar no nivel que você pretende.